# Concatenating video clip with static image causes buffer errors

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate a 15 second clip of a video (`MOVIE.mp4`) with 5 seconds (no audio) of an image (`IMAGE.jpg`) using `FFmpeg`.

Something seems to be wrong with my filtergraph, although I'm unable to determine what. The command I've put together is the following:

```sh
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -I IMAGE.jpg \
-t 15 -I MOVIE.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640[1_v];anullsrc[1_a];[1:v][1:a][1_v][1_a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]" \
-map "[out]" \
-strict experimental tst_full.mp4
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be creating some strange results:

1. On my personal computer (`FFmpeg 4.2.1`) it correctly concatenates the movie with the static image; however, the static image lasts for an unbounded length of time. (After entering `ctrl-C`, the movie is still viewable, but is of an extremely long length--e.g., 35 min--depending on when I interrupt the process.)
2. On a remote machine where I need to do the ultimate video processing (`FFmpeg 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`), the command does not terminate, and instead, I get cascading errors of the following form:

```
Past duration 0.611458 too large
...
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x21135a0] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
...
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x21135a0] 100000 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
```

I haven't been able to find much documentation that elucidates what these errors mean, so I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) pointed out, you only have to add `atrim` to your audio:

`anullsrc,atrim=0:5[silent-audio]`

Instead of `scale` you could use `scale2ref` and `setsar` to automatically make your image the same size and aspect ratio as the video.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i IMAGE.jpg \
-t 15 -i MOVIE.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]scale2ref[img][v];[img]setsar=1[img]; \
anullsrc,atrim=0:5[silent-audio];[v][1:a][img] 
[silent-audio]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]" \
-map "[out]" \
-strict experimental tst_full.mp4
```

Alternatively you could use `anullsrc` as a 3rd input:

```
ffmpeg \
-t 15 -i MOVIE.mp4 \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i IMAGE.jpg \
-f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[img][v];\
[img]setsar=1[img];[v][0:a][img][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]" \
-map "[out]" \
-strict experimental tst_full.mp4
```

Comment: The issue isn't the placement of anullsrc but that it is not of finite duration. Adding `atrim=0:5` after anullsrc in the OP's command will work as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Gyan. I've edited my answer accordingly.
One more thing I've noticed. If I use `scale2ref` in this short notation, the order of the input does matter. Because if I input the video first, it fails. My hypothesis is that `scale2ref` defaults to `[0:v][1:v]scale2ref[out-0_v][out-1_v]`. If you only type `scale2ref[out-0_v][out-1_v]` and `0:v` is the reference, it fails. Maybe omitting the inputs for `scale2ref` is not a good idea...

Comment: For any filter, if the input labels aren't provided, it will connect with first, any unconnected filter outputs within the graph, any unconnected input streams. So, always label to prevent unexpected connections.

Comment: Thank you! I've added input labels to the `scale2ref` filter.